# Full screen background video with HTML5

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I'm using the html5 video to display a background video for a site I'm building. I want it to fill the whole screen and be responsive, but there seems to be a gap in the bottom.

```css
 .video {
      position:absolute;
      height:100% !important;
      width:100%;
      top:0;
      right: 0;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
 }
 video{
      position:absolute;
      width:100% !important;
      max-height: 100% !important;
      background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<div class="video" >
    <video autoplay loop poster="../img/grazing.jpg" class="fillWidth">
        <source src="../videos/CowType.webm"
        type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
        <source src="../videos/CowType.mp4"
        type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    </video>
</div>
```

And here is a link to the site:http://capelos.gonzbergagency.com/prime.html

Comment: In my screen it looks like you want it to look, the video is full page and no gap at the bottom when I access http://capelos.gonzbergagency.com/

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong link. it is supposed to be: http://capelos.gonzbergagency.com/prime.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the video

```
video{
  position: fixed; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

be sure to delete this from the existing video CSS

```
video{
  width: 100% !important; 
  max-height: 100% !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it. It fills the screen, but it do not scale properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
html,
body,
div,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```